# What will happen during the JVM runtime in this case?

Tags: java, jvm, polymorphism

Assume that compiler ignored the type check for a.sayB() statement so we could run our program.

What would have happened during the runtime?

```
A a = new B();
a.sayB();   // compile time error
...

class A {
    public void sayA() {
        System.out.println("method of class A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void sayB() {
        System.out.println("method of class B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would work as expected because your `a` **is** a `B`. You could add a cast, and do it in practice. Like,

```
A a = new B();
((B)a).sayB();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was not asking about casting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. You say *if* the compiler didn't stop you, what would happen. The compiler has to stop you because at compile time that method invocation is resolved to a symbol that needs to be looked up from the class declaring the method.

The method "sayB(void)" doesn't exist outside the context of your class B declaration.

With reflection you could say (necessary exception handling omitted):

```
Method sayBMethod = B.class.getMethod("sayB");
// you now have a reference to the method itself and can try invoking it on your instance

sayBMethod(a)
```

This will attempt to invoke the method on the instance a, and will throw an IllegalArgumentException is a is not a B. Note though that even if a were of another type that also has a method sayB(), it would still fail. The method name has already been resolved at either compile time (in your example) or at the time we reflectively look up the method on class B.

If you tried

```
A.class.getMethod("sayB")
```

you'd simply get a NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: This would work though: 
`A a = new B();`
`Method sayB = a.getClass().getMethod("sayB");`
`sayB.invoke(a);`

Comment: With `method of class B` output

Comment: @HappyTorturer Yes. **But**, that is because `a.getClass()` returned `B.class`.